# Is there something wrong with my Phaser setup?

Tags: phaser-framework, parceljs

Im setting up my environment for my first PhaserJs project. The document loads but not the Phaser code, i checked my devtools and seeing this error. Im using VSCode an installed Phaser using npm and parcel.

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: AUTO is not defined
at Object.parcelRequire.main.js.phaser (main.js:9)
at newRequire (main.1f19ae8e.js:47)
at main.1f19ae8e.js:81
at main.1f19ae8e.js:120
```

Some people said they created their own config file or webpack but i don't know how to go about this.

Comment: Without seeing a bit of code it is hard to say. but you can look at this template https://github.com/ourcade/phaser3-parcel-template, that is template which discribes all setup steps and should work as is.

Comment: If you want a webpack starter template here is one from the phaser github, https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser3-project-template

Comment: Did the link's help or do you need some more help?